# Полноценное изменение языка в приложении android

Tags: java, android, локализация

У меня в приложении на android нужно сделать полноценное изменение локали. Будет менюшка, в которой будет список языков. При нажатии на элемент меню с языком, нужно менять язык `runtime` что значит на лету. Дальше после изменения языка, нужно его сохранить в настройках и дальше менять язык на следующих активити при их создании. Так же нужно сделать так, чтобы выбранный язык сетился и после перезагрузки приложения.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

После долгих и постоянных попыток, я все-таки смог решить свою проблему. У меня есть менюшка со списком языков:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, CountrycodeActivity.class);
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.lang:
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            return true;

        case R.id.support:
            Intent error = new Intent(this, Problem.class);
            startActivity(error);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String countryCode = data.getStringExtra(CountrycodeActivity.RESULT_CONTRYCODE);
        String lang = "en";
        sp = getSharedPreferences("language", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        switch (countryCode) {
            case "English":
                lang = "en";
                editor.putString("language", lang);
                break;
            case "Русский":
                lang = "ru";
                editor.putString("language", lang);
                break;
            case "Українська":
                lang = "uk";
                editor.putString("language", lang);
                break;
        }
        editor.apply();
        changeLang(lang);
    }
}
```

дальше у меня есть методы для изменения и сохранения языка:

```
private void changeLang(String lang) {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);

    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    saveLocale(lang);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

private void saveLocale(String lang) {
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("def_loc", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(langPref, lang);
    editor.apply();
}
```

вообще на этом этапе в приложении язык меняется runtime, но дальше нужно как-то при создании активити получать сохраненный язык и создавать активити уже с нужным языком. Вот в методе `onCreate()` я вставил такой кусок кода:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
sp = getSharedPreferences("language", 0);
String lang = sp.getString("language", "ru");
Locale locale = new Locale(lang);

Locale.setDefault(locale);
// Create a new configuration object
Configuration config = new Configuration();
// Set the locale of the new configuration
config.locale = locale;
// Update the configuration of the Accplication context
getResources().updateConfiguration(
        config,
        getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
);
setContentView(activity_login);
```

вроде у меня все работает, но возможно кто-то посоветует как-то улучшить мой способ. В любом случае надеюсь что это кому-то кроме меня поможет.

P.S. Вот только вспомнил, для того чтобы все нормально прижилось в приложении нужно сделать несколько файлов с переводом на нужный вам язык. Я делал не через встроенный `editor` студии, а создавал новый файлы. Это так на всякий случай, может это на что-то повлияет.

Comment: Используйте `Ctrl+K` для уменьшения/увеличения отступов в блоках кода

Comment: да я увидел по вашей правке что вы имеете в виду, так код становится приятнее читать) спасибо за совет.

Comment: Тогда при старте каждой активити нужно будет тянуть за собой этот код везде, не очень хорошее решение, должен быть другой выход.

Comment: да нет вроде не нужно)) я сделал два месте в программе где можно поменять язык, в остальных активити я просто тяну переменную из настроек при создании активити

Comment: Я не могу поверить, что для переключения языка внутри приложения разработчики Андроид Студио не могут сделать решение (функцию)... Причем с каждой новой ОС это переключение сделать все невозможнее и невозможнее...

Comment: На новых оперционках (например, Андроид 9,10) это уже не будет работать

Comment: @user_MGU, у меня на 9 работает вроде нормально))