# Помогите подправить логику приложения

Tags: android, activity

У меня приложение на `android` в котором есть такие активити: экран логина (LoginActivity), главный экран (MainScreen). Логика такая - пользователь при логине вводит пароль и юзернейм и если все ок, если сервер прислал свое одобрение, то дальше мы переходим на главный экран. На экране логина есть тулбар, на котором висит кнопка выбора языка приложения. Весь принцип изменения языка я описывал в своем предыдущем вопросе: [Полноценное изменение языка в приложении android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879444/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-android). То есть при нажатии на элемент списка  у меня автоматом делается пересоздание `LoginActivity` и сохраняется язык, для последующих активити и для сета после перезагрузки приложения.

А теперь в чем именно моя проблема: если заполнить поля с логином и юзернеймом и дальше не нажимать на кнопку для отправки запроса на сервер. Вместо отправки запроса на сервер, мы решаем что нужно предварительно изменить язык в приложении, и соответственно нажимаем на кнопку на тулбаре -> дальше выбираем язык из списка и нажимаем на него. При этом поля висят заполненные но кнопка "Войти" не нажималась. И тут происходит какая-то магия)) После выбора языка, у меня делается `recreate` активити, но я почему-то перехожу на главный экран, хотя у меня стоит четкое условие, что переходить на главный экран, только при двух условиях - если пользователь уже ранее пользовался приложением, либо пользователь нажал на кнопку и с сервера пришел удовлетворительный ответ.

Вот два упоминания главного экрана, на который осуществляется переход:
1)

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

2)

```
sp = getSharedPreferences(REFRESH_TOKEN, MODE_PRIVATE);
final boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);
user.setChecked(hasVisited);
if (hasVisited) {
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: В каких случаях в ``hasVisited`` записывается ``true``?

Comment: если пользователь логинился хоть раз, `false` ставится если пользователь нажал логаут

Comment: А это что делает: ``user.setChecked(hasVisited);``?

Comment: это чекбокс ставится, сейчас могу дополнить ответ, если вам эта информация поможет

Comment: Похоже, что в ``hasVisited`` считывается ``true``. Посмотрите значение переменной после считывания в процессе выполнения.

Comment: @Эникейщик, не могли бы объяснить поподробнее, не очень понятно если честно, насколько я понял то где-то ставится `hasVisited` `true`. Но эта переменная ставится `true` только когда нажимается кнопка

Comment: я не правильно сказал, эта переменная зависит от того, выбран чекбокс или нет.

Comment: Поставьте брейк на той строчке и посмотрите значение переменной во время выполнения. Вы ту переменную обнуляете? В смысле ``false`` туда записывается когда-нибудь? А то, может, один раз записали туда ``true`` и оно там теперь навсегда.

Comment: да эта переменная ставится `false` когда человек делает логаут

Comment: Ставится или вы думаете, что ставится? Говорю же, проверьте, что там считывается.

Comment: так, у меня появилась более точная информация, вся логика страдает если выбран чекбокс "запомнить пользователя" то есть если ввести все в поля, нажать на чекбокс, и дальше сделать изменения языка, то закономерно что после пересоздания активити сразу будем идти на второе активити)) но теперь вопрос как это исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как ни странно, но я походу нашел решение своей проблемы. Итак начнем сначала: проблема была такая - если мы вводим пароль и логин в поля на экране логина, и после этого нажимаем чекбокс "запомнить пользователя", то после того как мы выбираем язык и пересоздаем активити наше приложение автоматические переходит на второе активити так как у нас висит в настройках, что пользователь уже здесь бывал)) Что я придумал (возможно криво, но это работает), при выборе нового языка нам нужно пересоздавать активити, я закинул такой кусок кода:

```
private void changeLang(String lang) {
        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return;
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = myLocale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        saveLocale(lang);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();

        sp = getSharedPreferences(REFRESH_TOKEN, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);

        if (hasVisited) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", false);
            editor.apply();
            changeLang(lang);
        } else {
            moveTo();
        }


    }

    private void moveTo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
```

как можно увидеть из кода, мы перед пересозданием активити, проверяем был ли активирован чекбокс, вытаскивая значение переменной из настроек. Если это значение правда, то есть чекбокс был выбран, то мы его автоматом переводим в состояние невыбран, опять проверяем, и дальше пересоздаем активити.

Не спорю что способ очень громоздкий, и может можно как-то иначе решить мою проблему, но на данном этапе этот способ работает и его придумал лично я. Поэтому я решил поделится результатами своих трудов, и возможно кто-то предложит усовершенствовать мой метод каким-то образом.

P.S. единственное что я не могу понять, так это почему у меня может нормально вытащится переменная только в том случае когда есть строка:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences(REFRESH_TOKEN, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

вернее меня напрягает не то что делает эта строка, а то что там есть переменная `REFRESH_TOKEN`. Я не могу понять на что она так влияет, но если ее заменить то ничего не работает.

Comment: Первый параметр в ``getSharedPreferences`` это имя настроек, которые читаются. Где-то в коде переменной ``REFRESH_TOKEN`` присваивается какое-то строковое значение и под этим именем сохраняются настройки ([справка](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) ).

Comment: @Эникейщик, вы совершенно правы, это тоже настройка, но почему-то когда я пробую считать настройки с именем `"hasVisited"` то у меня не работает то что я сделал.

Comment: Это разные вещи. В данном случае: REFRESH_TOKEN - имя файла, где хранятся настройки (их - настроек, да и файлов тоже - может быть много). hasVisited - имя одного единственного параметра настроек, который хранится в файле с именеме указанным в REFRESH_TOKEN.

Comment: хорошо тогда закономерный вопрос, может не нужно создавать кучу файлов настроек, может просто создавать один файл куда и писать все настройки?? где я могу посмотреть доки которые создаются в процессе работы программы?

Comment: Да конечно не надо. Разве что в приложении 100500 настроек и хочется их разделить логически. А хранятся они где-то в папке приложения, что-нибудь вроде ``/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml`` или похожее на это ([вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146106/where-are-shared-preferences-stored))