# Внедрение мультиязычности в приложение android?

Tags: java, android

Итак, есть приложение, написанное на Java под Android в Android Studio. 
На сколько сложно подключить (добавить) второй язык?

**Необходимо реализовать:**

1. Смену язык1 на язык2 и наоборот
2. При смене язык1 на язык2 и наоборот, меняется основное меню
3. При смене язык1 на язык2 и наоборот, меняются вспомогательные
   действия (подтверждающие сообщения, title страниц, кнопки и меня (в общем весь string.xml) и тд)

Если да, то на какой бюджет мне примерно рассчитывать?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой ответ вам да, достаточно легко реализовать локализацию в приложении. На данный момент я как раз занимаюсь этим вопросом, и могу вас успокоить что это не так страшно как думаешь вначале)) Я конечно могу вам все долго расписывать, но у меня уже есть ответ на ваш вопрос, который я написал на свой же вопрос)) [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879444/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-android) ссылка. Я использовал менюшку для этих целей, но вообще принцип должен быть понятен.

Но давайте пойдем по вашим вопросам:

1. сменить язык вы сможете спокойно, как при помощи моего способа, так и при помощи сторонних библиотек, все зависит от вашего усердия и от времени выделенного на проект.
2. Понятие меняется основное меню очень растяжимое, если идет речь про меню-шторку, то там все просто - перекидываете все в ресурсы строк, и потом меняете как хотите.
3. Вспомогательные действия будут тоже меняться если вы будете вызывать строковые ресурсы с нужным кодом.

Вообще все довольно просто, лично у меня по-максимуму все строки находятся в ресурсе, и дальше просто магия)) На самом деле, нужно запарится над созданием кучи файликов с этими строками, только на других языках. Но вообще не волнуйтесь, это как оказалось, довольно простая задача.

Если будут вопросы или возникнут сложности, то не стесняйтесь и пишите, помогу чем смогу. Удачи :)

Comment: круто! Как с Вами связаться ? :)

Comment: по поводу чего вы хотите связаться со мной?

Comment: по поводу Ваше решения

Comment: Здесь пишите, не бойтесь что ваши вопросы здесь увидят, просто тогда коллективно мы вам быстрее поможем, а в чем возникла сложность?

Comment: Сложность в том, что я ищу программиста :) Заказчик отдал аппликацию и благополучно слился, взяв еще задаток 50%.

Хотя, быть может я сам попытаюсь реализовать, но не уверен.

PS: в аппликации НЕТ еще переключателя языка Ж)

Comment: Проблема в том что я на данный момент занимаюсь большим проектом один, поэтому помочь врядли смогу, если возникли сложности с реализацией моего способа, то пишите здесь и я быстрее отвечу, сейчас почти никуда не выхожу кроме как сюда, работы много))) в чем именно возникли сложности??

Comment: Я не программист :) Ладно, буду тыкаться завтра. Спасибо

Comment: вы смогли бы помочь за $$?

Comment: вот моя почта - angoran16@gmail.com. Все вопросы, предложения и пожелания вы можете написать туда. Здесь я думаю не стоит обсуждать такие вопросы - администрация будет совсем недовольна :)